# Why is my variable not being set in Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In my GameManager singleton object I create:

```
// Load levels
        // Create array property to store level objects
        self.levels = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        //Create 2 level objects with spawnRates
        Level *level1 = [[[Level alloc] initWithLevelNum:1 spawnRate:10000 bgImageName:@"Icon.png"] autorelease];
        Level *level2 = [[[Level alloc] initWithLevelNum:2 spawnRate:10000 bgImageName:@"Icon.png"] autorelease];
        Level *level3 = [[[Level alloc] initWithLevelNum:3 spawnRate:80 bgImageName:@"Icon.png"] autorelease];
        Level *level4 = [[[Level alloc] initWithLevelNum:4 spawnRate:80 bgImageName:@"Icon.png"] autorelease];
        Level *level5 = [[[Level alloc] initWithLevelNum:5 spawnRate:2 bgImageName:@"Icon.png"] autorelease];
        Level *level6 = [[[Level alloc] initWithLevelNum:6 spawnRate:1 bgImageName:@"Icon.png"] autorelease];
        //Put level objects into array property
        [_levels addObject:level1];
        [_levels addObject:level2];
        [_levels addObject:level3];
        [_levels addObject:level4];
        [_levels addObject:level5];
        [_levels addObject:level6];
        //Set current level index to 0
        self.curLevelIndex = 0;
```

And further down the line, I implement methods to be called by layers like so:

```
- (Level *)curLevel {
    NSLog(@"curLevelIndex is %d", _curLevelIndex);
    //returns object at current level index where at start, first slot [0] = spawnrate = 1
    return [_levels objectAtIndex:_curLevelIndex];
}

- (void)restartGame {
    _curLevelIndex = 0;
    [self nextLevel];
}

- (void)levelComplete {
    NSLog(@"curLevel spawnRate is %d", [self curLevel].spawnRate);

    //Increase currentlevelindex
    _curLevelIndex++;

    if (_curLevelIndex >= [_levels count]) {
        _curLevelIndex = 0;
        NSLog(@"resetting levels");
    } else {
        //make it faster
        //NSLog(@"current level %d", [[_levels objectAtIndex:_curLevelIndex].spawnRate ];
        NSLog(@"new level %d", _curLevelIndex);
    }

}
```

Please excuse all the NSLogs but im going crazy trying to find out why my spawnRate is not being changed.  In my game's update method I do this:

```
if (timeSinceLastRateBump > 3) {
        NSLog(@"DIFFICULTY INCREASES NOW>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        [[GameManager sharedGameManager] levelComplete];
        timeSinceLastRateBump = 0;
    }
```

And this is called every second more or less.  Now Im getting this in my NSLog:

```
2013-04-13 11:08:22:489 MZ[1408:3079] target added to _targets
2013-04-13 11:08:23:489 MZ[1408:3079] target added to _targets
2013-04-13 11:08:24:472 MZ[1408:3079] DIFFICULTY INCREASES NOW>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2013-04-13 11:08:24:473 MZ[1408:3079] curLevelIndex is 1
2013-04-13 11:08:24:474 MZ[1408:3079] curLevel spawnRate is 0
2013-04-13 11:08:24:475 MZ[1408:3079] new level 2
2013-04-13 11:08:24:509 MZ[1408:3079] target added to _targets
2013-04-13 11:08:25:506 MZ[1408:3079] target added to _targets
2013-04-13 11:08:26:522 MZ[1408:3079] target added to _targets
2013-04-13 11:08:27:490 MZ[1408:3079] DIFFICULTY INCREASES NOW>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2013-04-13 11:08:27:491 MZ[1408:3079] curLevelIndex is 2
2013-04-13 11:08:27:493 MZ[1408:3079] curLevel spawnRate is 0
2013-04-13 11:08:27:494 MZ[1408:3079] new level 3
2013-04-13 11:08:27:523 MZ[1408:3079] target added to _targets
2013-04-13 11:08:27:856 MZ[1408:3079] Globals called. Points: 1
2013-04-13 11:08:27:856 MZ[1408:3079] Globals leaving. Points: 2
2013-04-13 11:08:28:539 MZ[1408:3079] target added to _targets
```

Which proves curLevelIndex is increasing from 0 to 1 to 2.  But the spawnRate remains at 0.  Why?

Comment: don't see any piece of code that change spawnRate value

Comment: show your Level class (setters, getters) for spawnRate

Comment: spawnRate is created differently for each Level instance.  I create 6 Level instances and put them into the self.levels array.  When the levelComplete method gets called, curLevelIndex gets ++ and thus the method -(Level*)curLevel which returns [self.levels objectAtIndex:_curLevelIndex]; should be returning the Level at the new curLevelIndex.

Comment: `
@interface Level : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) int levelNum;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float spawnRate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *bgImageName;
- (id)initWithLevelNum:(int)levelNum spawnRate:(float)spawnRate bgImageName:(NSString *)bgImageName;
@end
` & `

@implementation Level
- (id)initWithLevelNum:(int)levelNum spawnRate:(float)spawnRate bgImageName:(NSString *)bgImageName {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.levelNum = levelNum;
        self.spawnRate = spawnRate;
        self.bgImageName = bgImageName;
    }
    return self;
}
@end`

Comment: The back ticks dont seem to be marking my code, sorry about that :(

Comment: instesd of posting in the comment, please put it as an edit in the main question so it is readable.

Comment: still cannot see any piece of code where you change your spawnRate value. so it is not strange that it is always 0

Comment: @Morion: I create an array of different Level objects each with a different spawnRate. To get a current Level I use the curLevel method which gets whatever Level is at the self.levels objectAtIndexPath = curLevelIndex.  So whenever I change the curLevelIndex value, I am changing the Level object returned by that method.  Since each Level object has a different spawnRate, the spawnRate should change, no?

Comment: your format specifier is wrong for logging spawnRate ... use %f. Your IDE should have given you a warning of sorts for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your levelComplete routine, instead of :

```
    NSLog(@"new level %d", _curLevelIndex);
```

do :

```
Level* current = [self curLevel];
NSLog(@"current level no : %d , spw rate : %f",current.levelNumber,current.spawnRate]; 
// *** WAG for the  getters.
```

and breakpoint on log. If current is nil, figure that out. If not, inspect the var and look at the spawn rate in that object.

Comment: I still get 0 for spawnRate.  current is not nil, i get my Level with my assigned spawnRate and everything :(

Comment: duh ... use %f to log your spawn rate. what you log is not what you have.

Answer (score 0):

in the code:

```
NSLog(@"curLevel spawnRate is %d", [self curLevel].spawnRate);
```

%d is used for a double value, not a float. change it to %f.